# Free Android off-line Texas Hold'em with strong AI

Tags: gratis, android

The title says it all

- Free
- Android
- off-line
- Texas Hold'em
- with strong AI

additionally:

- I prefer to have limit, although I won't object to having pot/no limit thrown in
- I prefer a ring game, but won't object to tournament on top of that
- In app purchases should be necessary to continue playing.
- Online play might be a nice bonus, for when I have wifi access, but off-line is a must

If it means anything to anyone out there, then I am looking for something as close to WilsonWare as possible, although I doubt that I will find anything that good. Again, the AI is the crux; preferably with a mix of players/tables; even better if they are user customizable.

I am a fairly tight, somewhat by the book, player (with enough variation to not get pushed off the pot too often).

B&M, I'll settle for 3/6 or 5/10, even 10/20 makes me nervous. So, if you are about that level/style & and can recommend an app, that would be ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case it helps anyone else, I have found and am extremely happy with 
[Governor of Poker 2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=air.com.youdagames.google.ww.gop2MobileFree&hl=en)

It is almost on a par with some PC based poker simulators.

> Play single player holdem poker on your Android and beat every cowboy
>   in Texas in this great Texas Hold'em Poker RPG game called Governor of
>   Poker 2.
>
> Millions of poker players have enjoyed Governor of Poker, without an
>   internet connection. With an easy Texas Holdem poker tutorial for
>   players that don't know how to play poker, but want to learn poker and
>   good opponents for star poker players with real poker skills! The
>   poker chips you win are required to buy houses, win transportation,
>   play against advanced poker AI opponents, win Texas and beat the new
>   Governor of Poker.
>
> TRY GOVERNOR OF POKER FOR FREE, THEN UNLOCK THE FULL POKER ADVENTURE
>   IN THE GAME!
>
> •Get ready for many hours and hours of Hold'm Poker play:
>   - Over 80 challenging poker players to beat;
>   - 27 stunning card saloons in 19 amazing Texas Holdem cities;
>   - Get hold of the five big poker assets.
>
> •Amazing Texas Poker AI Engine: A great new poker engine will
>   challenge poker beginners and world poker champions alike. Refine your
>   tactics to match the countless poker playing styles of your opponents
>   and watch them go "Steamy" and Tilt after showing off your great card
>   bluffs! Players will play better in each new city and poker
>   tournament, no cheating allowed!
>
> •Full Story: Governor of Poker 2 starts where the first game ended. A
>   new Dallas government decided to put a ban on all Texas Holdem poker
>   games and now considers the game to be illegal. Time to take matters
>   in your own hands and prove them wrong! Poker isn't a game of luck,
>   but requires poker skill.
>
> •Play Always and Everywhere Offline Poker, no internet connection
>   required: Because there is no live internet connection needed to play
>   a good game of Texas hold'em poker, you can just play Governor of
>   Poker 2 offline anywhere you want! Don't wait for human players in
>   multiplayer poker games, that don't respond or leave the pokergame or
>   go allin all the time. Just play this offline poker game !
>
> •Customize poker characters: Prove you are a bigshot by customizing
>   your poker style to fit your reputation. Be sure to visit one of the
>   many great hat shops across Texas and get yourself the poker deluxe
>   hat of your dreams! The game includes HD Poker graphics for a great
>   experience on all Android phones and tablets.
>
> Travel through Texas by Train, Casino Boat or Stage Coach and play
>   poker whilst on your way to the next poker city in Texas. Every city
>   has lots of exciting cash games and big poker tournaments with even
>   bigger Chip prizes, competition and bigger tournaments. You’ll
>   experience more checks, calls, raises, folds and all-ins than you can
>   imagine! Enjoy sit-n-go tournaments, Shootout tournaments, Bounty
>   tournaments, Cash games.
>
> ** NO INTERNET CONNECTION REQUIRED ** You don't need an internet connection and don't have to wait for other poker players, it's an
>   offline poker game.
>
> Have you always been a Texas holde'm pokee fanatic? You'll love
>   Governor of Poker 2! What are you waiting for partner? Click install,
>   download and prove you're worthy of the great poker title: GOVERNOR OF
>   POKER !

[image]